# Play Json: defining a Reads[T] that parses a JSON array and ignores certain elements

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an abstract type `PolyType` and concrete implementations of this type, `TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC`. The goal is to parse JSON arrays which contain serialized representations of these three types. Each array can contain all three types at the same time.

I'm using the following `Reads` for deserialization:

```
implicit val polyReads = new Reads[PolyType] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[PolyType] =
      json.validate(
        typeAReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[TypeA]) orElse
        typeBReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[TypeB]) orElse
        typeCReads.map(_.asInstanceOf[TypeC])
      )
}
```

Eventually, I can use it like this to parse a JSON array that contains these three types:

```
val json: JsValue = { ... }
val result = json.validate[Seq[PolyType]] 

// => JsResult[Seq[PolyType]], Seq contains instances of A, B and C
```

*This works conceptually*. The result is a `Seq[PolyType]` which contains instances of `TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC`. Notice how I don't have to deal with the `Seq` manually, e.g. I don't need to check explicitly if the input represents a json array (if it doesn't, I get a `JsError`, which is fine).

---

But what I really want to do:

First of all, extract *only* `TypeA` instances. This is because `TypeA` contains definitions that are needed to properly parse `TypeB` and `TypeC`. So the `Reads` for `TypeB` and `TypeC` are "dynamic" and require concrete instances of `TypeA`. I don't have problems defining those "dynamic" `Reads` for B and C.

But I wonder:

- How can I *first* extract `TypeA` and *later* on `TypeB/C` from *the same* json structure?
- E.g. just doing `val a = json.validate[Seq[TypeA]]` won't work since the json array also contains the other two types which will lead to an error.

Comment: What is the final type of the Seq you want to construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how `TypeA` is used to extract `TypeB` and `TypeC`, so I can only tell you how to extract all instances of `TypeA`. First, some example types:

import play.api.libs.json._

```
trait PolyType

case class TypeA(a: String) extends PolyType

case class TypeB(b: String) extends PolyType

case class TypeC(c: String) extends PolyType

implicit val typeAReads: Reads[TypeA] = Json.reads[TypeA]
implicit val typeBReads: Reads[TypeB] = Json.reads[TypeB]
implicit val typeCReads: Reads[TypeC] = Json.reads[TypeC]
```

Example data:

```
val json = Json.parse("""
    [
        {"a": "Some A"},
        {"b": "Some B"},
        {"c": "Some C"},
        {"c": "Other C"},
        {"a": "Other A"},
        {"b": "Other B"}
    ]
""")
```

Then, I define a `Reads[Seq[TypeA]]` that will first attempt to `validate` the JSON as `JsArray`, then individually `validate` each member of the array as `TypeA`, and `collect` only those that succeeded.

```
implicit val typeASeqReads = new Reads[Seq[TypeA]] {
    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Seq[TypeA]] = {
        js.validate[JsArray].map { array =>
            array.value.map(_.validate[TypeA])
                .collect { case JsSuccess(a, _) => a }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
scala> json.validate[Seq[TypeA]]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Seq[TypeA]] = JsSuccess(ListBuffer(TypeA(Some A), TypeA(Other A)),)
```

Caveats:

- This will *always* return `JsSuccess` unless the JSON is not an array. So if there are no valid `TypeA`s, it will return an empty `Seq`.
- It will be very difficult to differentiate between `TypeA`s that are not valid, and other types.

In the end, you'll need a special `Reads[Seq[PolyType]]` that can handle the requirement of making multiple passes through the list.

Comment: Thanks m-z. The caveats were too much of a problem for me since they interfere with the whole "reads-evaluation-chain". What I did eventually is reading all three types at the same time and using a combination of call-by-name parameters and lazy vals to refer to elements of `TypeA` which are not known yet. In the end I still need a second loop to check if the lazy references are valid, but the whole thing works.